# How to revoke explain plan privilege in mysql for a user? is it possible

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

How to revoke explain plan privilege in mysql for a user? is it possible

Please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific [privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges) for EXPLAIN in MySQL.